# importing data from one database to other when schemas are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have this SQL Server 2005 DB and we are upgrading to a new DB in SQL Server 2008. The schemas would be slightly different between the databases. What would be a best option to copy data from the old DB to the new DB.

Comment: I would recommend looking into the BCP utility http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Define "slightly different". [Integration Service](http://http:/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since the schemas are only slightly different, I would suggest making a full backup of the SQL2005 DB and restoring it on the SQL2008 server.  Once you have the direct copy, use a script to migrate the data on the few tables where the schema is different.

It really depends on the definition of slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integration Service to design a whole package, or you can connect to the 2005 instance from within 2008 SSMS and right click on the tables and select "Import Data".  This will bring up an Wizard that will do the work for you (through SSIS) and let you copy the data right over.

Another option is to use SQL Server Data Tools, which is a new tool from MS that has a schema compare tool where you can actually generate the scripts to create the tables and related objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686